# Telerik Rad Chart shows blurred black image

Tags: wpf, telerik, radchart

I am using Telerik Rad Chart in my WPF application to plot some graph.
The problem is when there is no data the chart shows a blurred black image.

[image: Telerik Chart Blurred Black Image]

Is there any way to get around so that the graph does not show this image when the data is not there.

Or i will be happy if there is some other thing that we can do.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there anyone who ever encountered this problem...??

Answer (score 0):

put this below code in .cs(code behind page)

chartname.PlotArea.EmptySeriesMessage.TextBlock.Text = "Data is not available";

this avoid the image and if there is no data it will display the message "data is not available".